# Oralce 12c Loop Through Multiple Start and End Dates and Find Specific Days Between Them

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have two main tables one that holds start & end dates and days of the week a class is in session.  The other table holds attendance of when a teacher took attendance.  What I need to do is for every class I need a list of the dates that a teacher didn't take attendance.  Below is what I have so far that works for one course but I am not sure how to loop through the "with clause" for each course (CRN).

code to use for testing

```html
CREATE TABLE SSRMEET 
(
  SSRMEET_TERM_CODE VARCHAR2(6 CHAR) NOT NULL 
, SSRMEET_CRN VARCHAR2(5 CHAR) NOT NULL 
, SSRMEET_START_DATE DATE NOT NULL 
, SSRMEET_END_DATE DATE NOT NULL 
, SSRMEET_SUN_DAY VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) 
, SSRMEET_MON_DAY VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) 
, SSRMEET_TUE_DAY VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) 
, SSRMEET_WED_DAY VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) 
, SSRMEET_THU_DAY VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) 
, SSRMEET_FRI_DAY VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) 
, SSRMEET_SAT_DAY VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)
,SSRMEET_SURROGATE_ID VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
)
CREATE TABLE SORATRK 
(
  SORATRK_SEQ_NO NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL 
, SORATRK_TERM_CODE VARCHAR2(6 CHAR) NOT NULL 
, SORATRK_CRN VARCHAR2(5 CHAR) 
)
CREATE TABLE SORSATR 
(
  SORSATR_SURROGATE_ID_SSRMEET NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL 
, SORSATR_PIDM NUMBER(9, 0) NOT NULL 
, SORSATR_MEET_DATE DATE NOT NULL 
)

Insert into SSRMEET (SSRMEET_TERM_CODE,SSRMEET_CRN,SSRMEET_START_DATE,SSRMEET_END_DATE,SSRMEET_SUN_DAY,SSRMEET_MON_DAY,SSRMEET_TUE_DAY,SSRMEET_WED_DAY,SSRMEET_THU_DAY,SSRMEET_FRI_DAY,SSRMEET_SAT_DAY,SSRMEET_SURROGATE_ID) values ('202131','112',to_date('07-JUN-21','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-JUL-21','DD-MON-RR'),null,'M','T','W','R',null,null,276309);
Insert into SSRMEET (SSRMEET_TERM_CODE,SSRMEET_CRN,SSRMEET_START_DATE,SSRMEET_END_DATE,SSRMEET_SUN_DAY,SSRMEET_MON_DAY,SSRMEET_TUE_DAY,SSRMEET_WED_DAY,SSRMEET_THU_DAY,SSRMEET_FRI_DAY,SSRMEET_SAT_DAY,SSRMEET_SURROGATE_ID) values ('202131','856',to_date('12-JUL-21','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('06-AUG-21','DD-MON-RR'),null,'M','T','W','R',null,null,278403);


Insert into SORATRK (SORATRK_SEQ_NO,SORATRK_TERM_CODE,SORATRK_CRN) values (20,'202131','112');
--Insert into SORATRK (SORATRK_SEQ_NO,SORATRK_TERM_CODE,SORATRK_CRN) values (21,'202131','856');

Insert into SORSATR (SORSATR_SURROGATE_ID_SSRMEET,SORSATR_PIDM,SORSATR_MEET_DATE) values (276309,9934,to_date('07-JUN-21','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into SORSATR (SORSATR_SURROGATE_ID_SSRMEET,SORSATR_PIDM,SORSATR_MEET_DATE) values (276309,9934,to_date('09-JUN-21','DD-MON-RR'));
```

sample output desired

[image]

Current code that works with the one CRN in the insert statement.  There is a commented out second insert.

```css
with attend as (
  select :crn  crn, 
            (select ssrmeet_surrogate_id
                                    from ssrmeet 
                                    join soratrk on soratrk_term_code = :term_select
                                    and soratrk_crn = ssrmeet_crn
                                    where ssrmeet_crn = :crn 
                                    and ssrmeet_term_code = :term_select) ssrmeet_surrogate_id,
                    
            (select ssrmeet_start_date - 1 
                    from ssrmeet 
                    join soratrk on soratrk_term_code = :term_select
                    and soratrk_crn = ssrmeet_crn
                    where ssrmeet_crn = :crn 
                    and ssrmeet_term_code = :term_select)  + level days_no_attendance_taken
   from   dual
  connect by level <= ((select nvl((select ssrmeet_end_date
                                        from ssrmeet 
                                        join soratrk on soratrk_term_code = :term_select
                                        and soratrk_crn = ssrmeet_crn
                                        where ssrmeet_crn = :crn 
                                        and ssrmeet_term_code = :term_select
                                        and ssrmeet_end_date < sysdate)
                                , sysdate) 
                    from dual)
- 
(select ssrmeet_start_date
                    from ssrmeet 
                    join soratrk on soratrk_term_code = :term_select
                    and soratrk_crn = ssrmeet_crn
                    where ssrmeet_crn = :crn 
                    and ssrmeet_term_code = :term_select)

  )
)
select :crn crn, days_no_attendance_taken 
  from   attend
where to_char ( 
days_no_attendance_taken, 
'fmday', 
'nls_date_language = english' 
  ) in ('monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday')

minus

 select distinct :crn crn, sorsatr_meet_date 
from sorsatr
join ssrmeet on sorsatr_surrogate_id_ssrmeet = ssrmeet_surrogate_id
and ssrmeet_crn = :crn
order by 2
```

I am following this example but need it to work for multiple start and end dates in the connect by level witin the with clause.

```css
with rws as (
  select date'2020-12-31' + level dt
  from   dual
  connect by level <= (
    date'2022-01-01' - date'2021-01-01'
  )
)
  select dt
  from   rws
  where  to_char ( 
    dt, 
    'fmday', 
    'nls_date_language = English' 
  ) = 'monday';
  
DT            
04-Jan-2021    
11-Jan-2021    
...
20-Dec-2021    
27-Dec-2021    

52 rows selected.
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added sample data and desired output.

Comment: Please provide the table structure and clarify the logic of your requirement in a bit more detail

Comment: _"I added sample data and desired output"_   Sample data, as in actual table DDL and INSERT statements ... in code, not images, so people can use it to test.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: EdStevens thanks for your comment.  I have create and inserts statements so that you can test. :-)

Comment: @Withnoe this is not a _minimal_ reproducible example. It is your own data with a million columns that are not relevant to the actual problem. It might help if you created a table from scratch just to illustrate the particular problem - remove any unnecessary joins and redundant tables and use explanatory column names. Once you're solved the core problem you can add more logic to your query.

Comment: Koen Lostrie thanks for your comment!  I simplified the table create and insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

Frank Kulash from the Oracle community gave me this answer which works.

```css
 SELECT   m1.ssrmeet_crn
,    c.a_date
FROM     ssrmeet m1
CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT m1.ssrmeet_start_date + LEVEL - 1 AS a_date
        FROM    dual
        CONNECT BY  LEVEL <=  1 + LEAST ( m1.ssrmeet_end_date
                        , SYSDATE - 1
                        )
                    - m1.ssrmeet_start_date
        )    c
WHERE   CASE TO_CHAR (c.a_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
       WHEN 'Sun' THEN ssrmeet_sun_day
       WHEN 'Mon' THEN ssrmeet_mon_day
       WHEN 'Tue' THEN ssrmeet_tue_day
       WHEN 'Wed' THEN ssrmeet_wed_day
       WHEN 'Thu' THEN ssrmeet_thu_day
       WHEN 'Fri' THEN ssrmeet_fri_day
       WHEN 'Sat' THEN ssrmeet_sat_day
     END                  IS NOT NULL
AND  m1.ssrmeet_crn       = :crn
AND  m1.ssrmeet_term_code = :term_select
  MINUS
SELECT   m2.ssrmeet_crn
,    a.sorsatr_meet_date
FROM     ssrmeet m2
JOIN     sorsatr a ON a.sorsatr_surrogate_id_ssrmeet = m2.ssrmeet_surrogate_id
  --
ORDER BY ssrmeet_crn
,        a_date
;    enter code here
```